# In what episode do we see a Klingon’s version of an officer’s alleged attack on him?

Tags: star-trek, episode-identification

Does anybody remember a *Star Trek* episode where a Klingon was testifying that a Federation officer - I think Riker - attacked him and it showed the Klingon's version of the story?

They had him saying "This is the Federation battleship..."

Comment: What research have you done? There are lots of sites with Episode listings and descriptions.

Comment: Why the downvote? @Paulie_D yes I have been searching for it and in the chat room for this SE site they suggested I ask here using this tag. That is what the tag is for.

Comment: I suspect you're referring to [DS9: Rules of Engagement](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_Engagement_(episode)) or possibly [VOY: Living Witness](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Living_Witness_(episode)). Both featured lawyers/historians trying to paint the Federation as bloodthirsty warmongers.

Comment: @Valorum I cant tell from the description but I will buy the ep and find out momentarily

Comment: @Hack-R I don't think that's it.

Comment: Trailer is here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJ71BaCnUh4

Comment: @Valorum i just checked it out thats not it but I see why you would think so

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvXDPjcDZCI it was Archer

Comment: @Hack-R - I'd suggest you self-answer; http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/45.htm - http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Judgment_(episode)

Comment: @Hack-R - "**DURAS:** *Viewer. Identify yourself.* 
**ARCHER** [on viewscreen]: *Captain Archer of the battle cruiser Enterprise.*"

Comment: Alright I will give you and Praxis a little time then self answer if neither of you want it.

Comment: @Hack-R : Glad you self-answered.  Credit where credit is due!  :-D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was Captain Archer in [ENT: Judgement](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Judgment_(episode))

> **DURAS:** ***Identify yourself.***
>
> ARCHER [on viewscreen]: ***Captain Archer of the battle cruiser
> Enterprise.***
>
> **DURAS:** *The people aboard your ship are wanted for treason. Surrender
> them immediately.*
>
> **ARCHER** [on viewscreen]: *By whose authority?*
>
> **DURAS:** *The Chancellor of the Klingon High Council.*
>
> **ARCHER** [on viewscreen]: *I don't know your Chancellor, and I don't give
> a damn what he wants. I've formed an alliance with these people, and
> I'm going to support their revolt.*
>
> **DURAS:** *Give them to me now, or I'll destroy your vessel.*
>
> **ARCHER** [on viewscreen]: *Fire one shot, and you'll be joining your
> ancestors in the afterlife.*

Comment: DURAS: Don't be a fool. Your ship is inferior. You won't survive a battle with us. 
ARCHER [on viewscreen]: **Death to the Empire.**

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my recollection, there is no such episode.

The phrase "This is the Federation battleship" does not appear in any Star Trek episode or film.

It does, however, appear in the Star Trek novel ***Rise of the Federation***:

> "Alien vessel, **this is the Federation battleship Thejal**".

([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q27XSyE71cIC&pg=PT101&lpg=PT101&dq=%22this+is+the+federation+battleship%22&source=bl&ots=abgnEUb-qN&sig=BCkmffCGh0BiL5XzhLmjMa5uxF0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJjKCotLPQAhVTImMKHQ9sAlkQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22this%20is%20the%20federation%20battleship%22&f=false))

However, this novel is set during the Earth-Romulan War, shortly after the events of *Enterprise*.

As **Valorum** points out in comments, this could be *DS9* ["Rules of Engagement"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/490.htm), where Worf is being investigated for an atrocity against the Klingons and is questioned by a Klingon attorney, but the phrase you mention does not appear in that episode, nor does it involve Riker.

Another candidate is *Voyager* ["Living Witness"](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voy/420.htm), where a Delta Quadrant culture recalls (incorrectly) their encounter with Voyager centuries ago.  A holo-recreation of the encounter features the following dialogue:

> **JANEWAY:** This is Captain Janeway of the **warship Voyager**. Break off your attack, or I'll destroy you.

The Doctor, a copy of whose program remained on that planet, is forced to hear these allegations and subsequently argue against them.

Comment: it was something very close to that, battleship, warship, attack vessel, etc. In the episode the Klingon really attacked first though and eventually got caught. He also said something like Death to the Klingon Empire in the fake flash back.

Comment: @Hack-R : Another possibility added.

Comment: I figured it out!!! It was Captain Archer. I knew it was one of those white males lol. Please add it to your answer and I will accept. I will get the link.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvXDPjcDZCI  Archer: "Death to the Empire"....lol sooo funny

Comment: @Hack-R : Sorry, I was away from my computer.  But I would have recommended that you do what you ended up doing: posting your own nice answer with your resolution to the problem!  Glad you figured it out.  (And I agree, it's hilarious!).